# Inspecting multiple Excel sheet at once

Tags: excel, file, directory, hidden-field

I have been given a folder of about 200 Excel spreadsheets and need to open each one of them and "inspect" them for hidden rows or sheets. Is there a way to do this without having to open each file individually?

Comment: Have you looked on here for questions doing similar things? “Looping” may be one term to start searching with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new Excel file, Open VBA Editor there, "Insert" -> "Module", paste the following code there:

```vb
Sub search_for_hidden_sheet_or_cells()
Dim oFSO As Object: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range: Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Dim r As Range

For Each f In oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Temp\test").Files
  If f.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(f)
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
      If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
        c = "Hidden sheet """ & ws.Name & """ in wb """ & wb.Name & """"
        Set c = c.Offset(1)
      ElseIf ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        c = "Very hidden sheet """ & ws.Name & """ in wb """ & wb.Name & """"
        Set c = c.Offset(1)
      Else
        For Each r In ws.UsedRange.Rows
          If r.Hidden Then
            c = "Hidden row " & r.Row & " in sheet """ & ws.Name & """ in wb """ & wb.Name & """"
            Set c = c.Offset(1)
          End If
        Next
        For Each r In ws.UsedRange.Columns
          If r.Hidden Then
            c = "Hidden col " & Split(r.Address, "$")(3) & " in sheet """ & ws.Name & """ in wb """ & wb.Name & """"
            Set c = c.Offset(1)
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
    wb.Close
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Instead of `"C:\Temp\test"` put in *your* folder address.

This code will find all sheets, columns and rows which are hidden in your Excel files. You will simply have to wait until the process finishes if there are many files. The result after my test looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell you can install Doug Finke's ImportExcel Powershell module

```
Find-Module ImportExcel | Install-Module
```

(ImportExcel help here 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/')

Then you can check .xlsx and .xlsm files for hidden sheets using the Get-ExcelSheetInfo option

```
$FolderPath = 'DriveLetter:\path to file'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Include *.xlsx, *.xlsm -File -Name
$array = @()
ForEach($File in $Files){ 
$row = Get-ExcelSheetInfo $File 
$array = $array + $row
}
$array | Out-GridView
```

For .xls files you will need to convert to .xlsx first for which there are many tools and scripts freely downloadable.